# In MVVM, should the View know about the model?

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm

A simple point of clarification.  I believe the answer is "no", but I want to be sure.

Is it proper for the View to have knowledge of the Model?

As I said, I think the answer should be "no", but I'm finding it hard to design a simple MVVM demo without having the view know about the model.

Comment: My opinion is that the answer is no as well, what framework are you using where a simple MVVM demo doesn't make separation easy?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a ViewModel in between? If you general feeling is that it will just be a redundant layer, I'll admit I felt this way many times, and it proved to be wrong constantly. You will be surprised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right.Answer is NO.

[
The View binds to properties on a ViewModel, which, in turn, exposes data contained in Model objects and other state specific to the view. 
The bindings between view and ViewModel are simple to construct because a ViewModel object is set as the DataContext of a view. 
If property values in the ViewModel change, those new values automatically propagate to the view via data binding. 
For example, when the user clicks a button in the View, a command on the ViewModel executes to perform the requested action. 
The ViewModel, never the View, performs all modifications made to the model data.
]
There's this useful link where you can have examples abouot this explanation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: You never use `DataTemplate`? If you use it on any `ItemsControl` and its subclass, usually will access some models in a list-like collection and their properties. If the view don't know about all the things of the model, how did you tell the view how to display the appropriate data?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes View should know the Model. When i use DataTemplate.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp2.MyView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" BorderBrush="Transparent" x:Name="mainListBox"
     Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="4">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Key" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName = mainListBox, Path = SelectedItem.Age}"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

As you seen, View knows my Model becouse of Name and Age

Comment: Very wrong answer. You should delete or improve it. The whole point of MVVM is to decouple the UI from your business models. The correct answer is: "**never** should the View know the Model".