# When using DataTemplate in mvvm, does the view need to know the model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

[In MVVM, should the View know about the model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731918/in-mvvm-should-the-view-know-about-the-model)

As zzfima answered in the example above, you can use something like DataTemplete.

In fact, when the property "Name" of Persons is changed to "PersonName", the XAML of the View must also change.

The correct mvvm structure I know of is:

[image]

But, as above, if the view knows the model, then the structure is:
[image]

Can we really say that the view doesn't know the model?

Assuming it knows, is there a way to "completely" isolate the view so that it doesn't know the model?

Comment: Your dependency graph is wrong. MVVM only has unidirectional dependencies. You must remove the arrow that points from Model towards View Model. To answer your question: if `Person` is a class of the Model, then Binding to it would indeed violate MVVM. The fact that it needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged indicates that it must be a class of the View Model. Don't confuse the term "model" or "data model" with the Model component of the MVVM architecture. The class `Person` is a data model in the domain of the View Model.

Comment: If the Model also contains an entity named `Person` you would have to convert it to a `Person` of View Model (new type) in order to decouple it from the View.

Comment: The answer you have referenced is simply wrong.

Comment: @playground: It depends on how your define "model". A model may be a service for example and the view shouldn't know about this one. If  the "model" is some kind of lightweight `Person` object, it's perfectly fine to bind directly to it from the view. But then it's more like a view model after all. What's a model in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much you are really willing to work on separation! All the examples in tutorials are not made to make full separation, they just wanna show working example.

If you use your domain models inside the ViewModel then the View knows about them. If you need to separate that - then u gonna have mapper that will map your domain models into the ViewModels that are only known to View!

The idea for MVVM is that you can swap your view easy and to have more control inside the ViewModel iteself.

Let's assume you have your `Customer` `Order` domain objects with logic inside of them , if u wanna present them to the View you gonna have `CustomerViewModel` and `OrderViewModel` which will be mapped from domain objects. And your `OrderDetailsViewModel` will be :

```
public class OrderDetailsViewModel

 { 
   public class CustomerViewModel {get; set;}
   public class OrderViewModel {get; set;}
 }
```

Comment: *"The idea for MVVM is that you can swap your view easy and to have more control inside the ViewModel iteself."* - The heat of an application is not the view. It's all about the business domain.  MVVM tries to decouple the business logic from the UI, so that you can develop and test it fully independent of the UI.